# Change .fit to .fits files

Tags: python, image-processing, physics, astropy, astronomy

Hi I am trying to process some images to perform astrophotometry in python. I had written a code that would work on .fits files, but my camera saves the new images in a .fit file. I tried the following to see if it could still process:

```
hdulist = fits.open(nameFile, ignore_missing_end=True)
Image = hdulist [0].data
```

but I am still getting errors as to how the file type is not useful, Thank you very much:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAZCw.png)

Comment: Im new to this and would be glad to share my jupyter file so far but not sure if that's okay on the site. Thanks

Comment: Why not just rename your file so it ends in `.fits`?

Comment: Are you sure your `.fit` files are not FITS files ? `.fits` is the canonical extension but sometimes `.fit` is used.

Comment: You can try to run `fitsinfo somefile.fit` (`fitsinfo` comes with Astropy), or have a look at the beginning of the file.

Comment: renaming then does not change the info in the files so it makes it worse.
I am sure they are not FITS, my code was written for FITS, but my camera saved the data as FIT. 

Ill try fitsinfo, and let u know. thank you.

Comment: Maybe you could share the file via Dropbox or Google Drive or somesuch?

Answer (score -2):

I have never heard of `.fit` file but you can try using [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#fits) which has `.fits`. With a code something like this:

```
from PIL import Image
Image.open("original.fits").save("new.png")
```

Comment: I would need the final stacked files as FITS ( or FIT that are visible). png does not contain enough info